# WPF color nodes based on view property

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a WPF treeview that I would like the color of a node to be based on a particular getter. I can't figure how to databind for that case. I would like it to look like [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/Treenodeforegroundandbackgroundcolortooltips.htm) except that odd numbers would be a child node of the even numbers

Comment: Why not use a Converter Class for your binding?

Comment: I believe you would need to use a DataTrigger in your DataTemplate for the node.

Comment: How do you use the `TreeView`? Do you use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, you can simply add a trigger:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlight}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```